# How to sign array like `address[]` with eip712 with golang

Tags: go-ethereum

```
var Types = core.Types{
    "EIP712Domain": {
        {
            Name: "name",
            Type: "string",
        },
        {
            Name: "version",
            Type: "string",
        },
        {
            Name: "chainId",
            Type: "uint256",
        },
        {
            Name: "verifyingContract",
            Type: "address",
        },
    },
    "Claim": {
        {
            Name: "users",
            Type: "address[]",
        },
        {
            Name: "amounts",
            Type: "uint256[]",
        },
        {
            Name: "user",
            Type: "address",
        },
        {
            Name: "nonce",
            Type: "uint256",
        },
        {
            Name: "deadline",
            Type: "uint256",
        },

    },

}

type Message struct {
    Users []string
    Amounts []string
    User string
    Nonce string
    Deadline string
}


func Sign(key *ecdsa.PrivateKey, data *core.TypedData) (hexutil.Bytes, error) {
    domainSeparator, err := data.HashStruct("EIP712Domain", data.Domain.Map())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    typedDataHash, err := data.HashStruct(data.PrimaryType, data.Message)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    rawData := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\x19\x01%s%s", string(domainSeparator), string(typedDataHash)))
    dataHash := crypto.Keccak256(rawData)

    signature, err := crypto.Sign(dataHash, key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    
    if signature[64] < 27 {
        signature[64] += 27
    }

    return signature, nil
}
```

I use the function Sign ,but report an error `data '[0x111da67948Ef5Ed1f82D707B8cd7e3B1DFa87AEa]' doesn't match type 'address[]'` ,can someone show me a demo,thanks

Answer (score 0):

try changing the array type to []interface{}